Compilation of inheritance chain
I came to know that given contracts
fileA.sol
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0;
contract A {}

is imported by
fileB.sol
import './fileA.sol';
pragma solidity 0.8.0;
contract B {}

where B is the top-level contract (whether inherits A or not), will be given the priority of compiler version for compilation. In other words, all the imports and code in fileB.sol will be compiled with 0.8.0 compiler (since fileA.sol has ambigous version set to support 0.8.0 as well)
How does compiler handle breaking changes ? For example, will arithmetic over/underflows will be duplicately checked (0.7.0 manual checks and 0.8.0 inherent checks) ?
